# Unity2D: Prefab not working with animator

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a prefab that is instantiate in using my spawning script. I also have a game over panel that slide [down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5Eg3t3glWs) (this is done by animation) once the player dies. The problem I'm having is that the needs to be game over panel attach to the prefab in the inspector window for the game over panel to work. This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1HaM.jpg) explains everything. Please help

Comment: do you have an animator component attached to your GameOverPanel?

Comment: @Milad Qasemi: Yes. I do

Answer (score 1):

in Unity you can't assign scene objects to prefabs because prefabs must be usable within all your scenes, so if a scene object was assignable to a prefab then the prefab couldn't be used in another scene.